# Creating UI of Microsoft Bot Framework

Tags: botframework

Is it possible to create my own UI on the top of Microsoft chatbot emulator ?
If yes, i want to design my chatbot's UI as complete different from the BLUE-WHITES boring micorosft's UI. Help me to achieve this geeks.

Comment: Please review: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is funny @EricDahlvang

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example (using the the last option mentioned by Nox)

Answer (score 8):

There are a large number of ways to do this and your approach will depend on your abilities and needs. If this will be in a mobile app the cleanest way would probably be to do this with xamarin using the rest api to allow for easy crossplatform.

If you are versed in web development using react and want a clean web view (the best web interface option) you can get the code base microsoft released [here.](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat) If you need it as a quick and dirty web view for testing you could inject css/js where it is needed.

If your web development skills are low but you want a clean stable interface (or you don't need a lot of customization) you could run a direct line website and just modify the css/js files hosted for the basic bots. I suggest downloading these hosted files instead of referencing them, this way you can directly manipulate it. This last option is actually what I am using. I plan to build a nice crossplatform view with xamarin when I get enough time to do so.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="bot"/>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPT -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js"></script>
    <script>
      BotChat.App({
        directLine: { secret: direct_line_secret },
        user: { id: 'userid' },
        bot: { id: 'botid' },
        resize: 'detect'
      }, document.getElementById("bot"));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

EDIT:
I forgot to mention that you can host this web interface for free on bitbucket and embed it into your mobile apps and you can host it in azure INSIDE your bot. You can do this by making a new index.html and in the web.config file where it has  default.htm you can replace that with index.html and host it out like that without needing an extra web host.

Comment: Great answer!  Thank you for this.

Answer (score 1):

Edit:  See Nox's great answer.

Edit2: I started skinning the webchat bot in an mvc application here: 
https://skinnedwebchatbot.azurewebsites.net/bot/webchat
https://github.com/EricDahlvang/SkinnedWebChat

There is an example of a modified webchat Bot on [education.microsoft.com](http://education.microsoft.com)

[image]

You can also use the DirectLine api, and create whatever front end you like: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a customized version of the Bot Framework Emulator, fork the repository [Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-Emulator). The app itself is built with [Electron](https://electron.atom.io/), the same technology behind apps such as [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) and [Slack](https://slack.com/).